# html and css with bootstrap: grid structure does not align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the grid structure by bootstrap to create a nice looking page. However, my div is moved and columns in rows are not aligned anymore:
[image]

The box with the three should be in line with the blue background. What am I doing wrong? What is the reason for this? I would like to understand. My code is:

**EDIT1**

I added `no-marg`to the `<h1>`but now it looks like this: How can I get to fill out the full height?
[image]

```css
.no-marg{
 margin:0 !important;
 padding:0 !important;
}

.sm-pad{
 padding:5px;
 background-clip:content-box;
}

.col-white{
 color:white;
}

.dark-theme {
 color: white;
 background-color:#17191B; 
 height: 100%;
}

#step-no{
 margin:20px;
}

.light-theme {
 color: black;
 background-color:#EFEFEF;
}

.cont-box {
 margin:6px;
 
}


body { 
background: black; 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row.equal {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}

.red-square{
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 0;
}

.btn:hover{
 background-color: #78BE20;
}



.blue-rectangle{
 background-color: #008ECF;
 border-radius: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="work_step_v1.css">
</head>


<body>

<div class="row equal">
 <div class="col-sm-1 red-square">
  <span style="font-size: 40px" class="col-white glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>&nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <h1 class="col-white">Step</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-1 red-square">
  <span style="font-size: 40px" class="col-white glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>&nbsp;
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row equal">
 <div class="col-sm-1 red-square">
  <span style="font-size: 40px" class="col-white glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>&nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-10 blue-rectangle">
  <div class="row equal">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="dark-theme">

    <h1 class="col-white">3</h1>  
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
    <span color<img alt="Warning Logo" src="./image/warning.svg">
   </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row equal">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
   </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-1 red-square">
  <span style="font-size: 40px" class="col-white glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>&nbsp;
 </div>
</div>





<script src="steps_v1.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box has a margin-top. Set it to 0

```css
.no-marg{
 margin:0 !important;
 padding:0 !important;
}

.sm-pad{
 padding:5px;
 background-clip:content-box;
}

.col-white{
 color:white;
}

.dark-theme {
 color: white;
 background-color:#17191B; 
 height: 100%;
}

#step-no{
 margin:20px;
}

.light-theme {
 color: black;
 background-color:#EFEFEF;
}

.cont-box {
 margin:6px;
 
}


body { 
background: black; 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row.equal {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}

.red-square{
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 0;
}

.btn:hover{
 background-color: #78BE20;
}



.blue-rectangle{
 background-color: #008ECF;
 border-radius: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="work_step_v1.css">
</head>


<body>

<div class="row equal">
 <div class="col-sm-1 red-square">
  <span style="font-size: 40px" class="col-white glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>&nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <h1 class="col-white">Step</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-1 red-square">
  <span style="font-size: 40px" class="col-white glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>&nbsp;
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row equal">
 <div class="col-sm-1 red-square">
  <span style="font-size: 40px" class="col-white glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>&nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-10 blue-rectangle">
  <div class="row equal">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="dark-theme">

    <h1 class="col-white no-marg">3</h1>  
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
    <span color<img alt="Warning Logo" src="./image/warning.svg">
   </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row equal">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
   </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-1 red-square">
  <span style="font-size: 40px" class="col-white glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>&nbsp;
 </div>
</div>





<script src="steps_v1.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did but now it aligns but leaves space. See edit 1 above please.

Comment: Set the padding-left to 0 on the grandfather div.col-sm-3

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: -webkit-box;` to `.dark-theme`

```css
.no-marg{
 margin:0 !important;
 padding:0 !important;
}

.sm-pad{
 padding:5px;
 background-clip:content-box;
}

.col-white{
 color:white;
}

.dark-theme {
 color: white;
 background-color:#17191B; 
 height: 100%;
 display: -webkit-box;
}

#step-no{
 margin:20px;
}

.light-theme {
 color: black;
 background-color:#EFEFEF;
}

.cont-box {
 margin:6px;
 
}


body { 
background: black; 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row.equal {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}

.red-square{
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 0;
}

.btn:hover{
 background-color: #78BE20;
}



.blue-rectangle{
 background-color: #008ECF;
 border-radius: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="work_step_v1.css">
</head>


<body>

<div class="row equal">
 <div class="col-sm-1 red-square">
  <span style="font-size: 40px" class="col-white glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>&nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <h1 class="col-white">Step</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-1 red-square">
  <span style="font-size: 40px" class="col-white glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>&nbsp;
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row equal">
 <div class="col-sm-1 red-square">
  <span style="font-size: 40px" class="col-white glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>&nbsp;
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-10 blue-rectangle">
  <div class="row equal">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="dark-theme">

    <h1 class="col-white">3</h1>  
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
    <span color<img alt="Warning Logo" src="./image/warning.svg">
   </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row equal">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
   </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-1 red-square">
  <span style="font-size: 40px" class="col-white glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>&nbsp;
 </div>
</div>





<script src="steps_v1.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can also call display:inline-block; width: 260px (what you need)